# How can I match this pattern of file name in a directory, and output the matched?

Tags: regex, linux, shell

there are many of files in this directory:

```
[ichen@ui01 data]$ ls
data.list
data.root
ntuple.data15_13TeV.00276262.DAOD_FTAG2.root
ntuple.data15_13TeV.00276329.DAOD_FTAG2.root
ntuple.data15_13TeV.00276336.DAOD_FTAG2.root
ntuple.data15_13TeV.00276416.DAOD_FTAG2.root
ntuple.data15_13TeV.00276511.DAOD_FTAG2.root
```

and i want to make a list which just contains those files which have the pattern of:

```
    [many chars].[many chars].[many numbers].[many chars].root
```

to match the file names such like:

```
ntuple.data15_13TeV.00276262.DAOD_FTAG1.root
ntuple.data15_13TeV.00276329.DAOD_FTAG2.root
ntuple.data15_13TeV.00276336.DAOD_FTAG3.root
etc...
```

how can I use regexp to achieve this goal? 
Maybe we can use this syntax:

```
for f in `ls`;do if [....];then echo $f;fi;done  > log.list
```

Comment: `pattern like` -> exactly like that? What do you mean exactly? Can you describe by words what should be the format or provide multiple examples for file names that would match?

Comment: @Dropout Hi, I edited my quesion to match your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regexp land, many roads lead to rome. :)

```
ls | egrep '^\w*\.\w*\.[0-9]*\.\w*\.root$'
```

^ marks the beginning of a line
$ marks the end of a line
\w is a word character
\w* is many work characters
. is a literal '.' character, an unmasked '.' in the regurlar expression stands for "any character"
[0-9] is any of the numbers between 0 and 9

And for your specific example:

```
for f in `ls`;do echo $f | egrep '^\w*\.\w*\.[0-9]*\.\w*\.root$';done
```

And now including the if statement:

```
for f in `ls`; do if [[ $f =~ '\w*\.\w*\.[0-9]*\.\w*\.root' ]]; then echo $f; fi; done
```

In this case, I had to remove the line beginning and end (^...$) for it to match. Not sure why. In general, =~ will check for regular expressions.

Comment: Than you. But how can I use this syntax :for f in `ls`;do if [....];then echo $f;fi;done  > log.list  ? Just for curious.

Comment: Added a for loop ... but it's not completely clear, which part of your syntax you want to keep.

Comment: If I want to use the "if", how can I achieve that?

Comment: the syntax I want to keep is the "if" structure.

Comment: Hello, I have tried your mehod: `for f in \`ls\`; do if [[ $f =~ '\w*\.\w*\.[0-9]*\.\w*\.root' ]]; then echo $f; fi; done` But it seems not work, there are nothing echoed. Maybe something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | grep '..*[.]..*[.][0-9][0-9]*[.]..*[.]root > log.list
```

should do the job

Comment: `.` outside [] matches any character once, `.*` outside [] matches zero or more characters, `[.]` matches exactly one dot

Comment: thanks! But how can I use the syntax like:for f in `ls`;do if [....];then echo $f;fi;done  > log.list.  I know your method would work, but I'm still curious.

Comment: not see any reason, but if... `for f in $( ls ) ; do echo "$f" |grep -q <expr from above>; test $? -eq 0 && echo $f; done`  ?  You can replace the test ... stuff with an if if needed.

Comment: you could also try to fiddle with shell regex itself but I can't tell exactly how from my head, I always experiment `test [[ $f =~ <...> ]] && echo "$f"`  The <> would be the same pattern that you could use on ls to list only the wanted files.,  You can replace the test ... stuff with an if if needed.

Comment: `if [[ $var =~ expr ]]` compares the value of $var to the shell-regex given in expr (not to be quoted), e.g. * as you write in a filename will match anything or [aA]* will match any string starting with a or A ... see your favorite shell reference

Comment: Hello, I used your method: `for f in \`ls\`;do test [[ $f =~ '\w*\.\w*\.[0-9]*\.\w*\.root'  ]] && echo "$f"; done` But there are a error: `-bash: test: too many arguments`, how about this? And i tried the usage of `if [[ $var =~ expr]]` like this `for f in \`ls\`; do if [[ $f =~ '\w*\.\w*\.[0-9]*\.\w*\.root' ]]; then echo $f; fi; done`but it seem not work, too. could you help me? Thank you!

Comment: No, one the one side, the combination of the \w word-character regex from grep and the shell-regex is not possible - on the other side it seems that the double square bracket expression works only with `if` but not with `test`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have found the way! The ' '  inside the double square bracket is not allowed. I used this method and successed:  for f in \`ls\`; do if [[ $f =~ ..*\...*\.[0-9]*\...*\.root ]]; then echo $f; fi; done

Comment: bang, should have noted - the right side on the matching operator explicitly requires it not to be quoted...well done

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be complicated like that. You just need to list out the files which match a certain pattern - wildcards are basically enough, there's no need for regexes.

```
ls -1 ntuple.data*.*.*.root > log.list
```

Comment: Thank you, but for my curious, I want to know the usage of regexp and the syntax like:  for f in 'ls'; do if [...];then echo $f; fi; done.    This could be used for some complicated cases.